# unable to compile GNOME planner from source

Tags: compiling, gnome3

I'm using fedora 23 64 bits here, i suppose i have all dev deps installed, however this last one i don't know how to solve:

```
[sombriks@sephiroth planner]$ sh autogen.sh 
/usr/bin/gnome-autogen.sh
***Warning*** USE_COMMON_DOC_BUILD is deprecated, you may remove it from autogen.sh
***Warning*** USE_GNOME2_MACROS is deprecated, you may remove it from autogen.sh
***Warning*** PKG_NAME is deprecated, you may remove it from autogen.sh
checking for automake >= 1.9...
  testing automake... found 1.15
checking for autoreconf >= 2.53...
  testing autoreconf... found 2.69
checking for intltool >= 0.25...
  testing intltoolize... found 0.51.0
checking for pkg-config >= 0.14.0...
  testing pkg-config... found 0.28
checking for gtk-doc >= 1.0...
  testing gtkdocize... found 1.24
Checking for required M4 macros...
**Warning**: I am going to run `configure' with no arguments.
If you wish to pass any to it, please specify them on the
`autogen.sh' command line.

Processing ./configure.ac
Running gtkdocize...
Running intltoolize...
Running autoreconf...
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force --warnings=no-portability 
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy --force
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in '.'.
libtoolize: copying file './ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: Consider adding 'AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])' to configure.ac,
libtoolize: and rerunning libtoolize and aclocal.
libtoolize: Consider adding '-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force --warnings=no-portability
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader --force --warnings=no-portability
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing --warnings=no-portability
configure.ac:6: warning: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE: two- and three-arguments forms are deprecated.  For more info, see:
configure.ac:6: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Modernize-AM_005fINIT_005fAUTOMAKE-invocation
configure.ac:10: installing './compile'
configure.ac:6: installing './missing'
automake: error: cannot open < xmldocs.make: No such file or directory
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
[sombriks@sephiroth planner]$
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While hitting the same problem I found out that the below helped:

```
touch xmldocs.make
```

Comment: Indeed it helped @kiwi ! ive forked from https://github.com/GNOME/planner and after touch this the configure procedure gave me a few missing deps and then i could compile it. the binary doesn't seem suable, i do not fully understand this build procedure or the specifics of planner compilation, yet i got it building and that's fine for the moment. thank you.